# Azure CLI - removing a parentheses

Tags: azure-cli, powershell-core

I'm running the following command using azure cli

`az functionapp config appsettings set --name $functionAppName --settings "encryptionKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=$keyValutName;SecretName=encryptionKey)"`

When I view the value it shows as

`"@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=MyVaultName;SecretName=encryptionKey"`

It's removing the end parentheses which breaks the key vault connection.

I think the problem is the semicolon, I can't use --% to stop processing as I need to resolve the $keyValutName.

Also think this is more of a powershell issue than az cli.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue when I run the CLI command in Powershell, to solve the issue, just use the command below.

```
$functionAppName = "joyfun"
$keyValutName = "joykeyvault123"
$setting = "encryptionKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=$keyValutName;SecretName=encryptionKey"+'")"'
az functionapp config appsettings set --resource-group xxxx --name $functionAppName --settings $setting
```

[image]